# The number of labeled pairs of edge disjoint trees and related questions

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, trees

I wonder what is known on the following:

1) What is the number $T_k(n)$ of $k$-tuples of (pairwise) edge-disjoint trees $(T_1,T_2,\dots, T_k)$ with $n$ labelled vertices?

2) (harder, it seems) What is the number $S_k(n)$ of subgraphs with $n$ labelled vertices which are union of $k$ (pairwise) edge-disjoint trees?

3)  What is the number $R_k(n)$ of $k$-tuples of (pairwise) edge-disjoint trees $(T_1,T_2,\dots, T_k)$ on the set of vertices $[n]={1,2,\dots,n}$ such that $T_i$ is a tree with $n-i$ edges?

4) (Like 2) What is the number $U_k(n)$ of subgraphs with $n$ labelled vertices which are union of $k$ (pairwise) edge-disjoint trees $(T_1,T_2,\dots, T_k)$ on the set of vertices $[n]={1,2,\dots,n}$ such that $T_i$ is a tree with $n-i$ edges?

(Added Sept 7, 2017): 5)  What is the number $F_k(n)$ of $k$-tuples of (pairwise) edge-disjoint forests $(F_1,F_2,\dots, F_k)$ on the set of vertices $[n]={1,2,\dots,n}$ such that $F_i$ is a spanning forest with $n-i$ edges?

6) Variant on 5): Rooted forests rather than forests. (Call the number $G_k(n)$.)

Of course, Cayley's formula for the number of trees on $n$ labelled vertices gives that $T_1(n)=S_1(n)=R_1(n)=U_1(n)=F_1(n)=G_1(n)=n^{n-2}$ but I wonder if something is known even for $k=2$.

Comment: Does each tree have to be on the $n$ vertices, or it can be a tree on a subset of those vertices?

Comment: On p81 of Moon, Counting Labelled Trees, there is a formula for the number of pairs of trees on $n$ vertices with exactly $m$ edges in common, but I didn't manage to get sensible numbers out of it.  Perhaps there is a typo.  ADDED: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematika/article/the-second-moment-of-the-complexity-of-a-graph/EAB4FE78E29B82075727C0844439C6C9

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: The formula looks reasonable to me. For $n=1,2,\dots$, I got the number of edge-disjoint ordered pairs of tress on the same $n$ vertices equal: 
    1, 0, 0, 12, 1140, 147240, 27351240, 7080803520, 2459711381904, 1109036355638400, ...

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev In the paper, the expression for $T_m(n)$ has $2^{2(n-m-2)}$ but in the book it has $2^{2(n-m-1)}$.  I get your values using the version in the paper and I agree they seem reasonable.  This sequence is not in OEIS.

Comment: In the case of Q2 for two spanning trees, there is a thm of Nash-Williams that a graph on $n$ vertices is the union of two spanning trees iff it has $2n-2$ edges and each subset $E'$ of the edge set  has $|E'| \le 2k-2$ where $k$ is the number of endpoints of $E'$.  I doubt that helps to count them.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Added this sequence as https://oeis.org/A291952 

A minor correction: in the formula there is $n^{2(n-m-2)}$, not $2^{2(n-m-2)}$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: It seems that the theorem by Nash-Williams covers the case of $k$ trees as well, at least that's what's said in Harari's book.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Very useful comment! I did not know about it. I would have accepted it as an answer :)  Thanks all for all the other comments.